# Observable emit array element

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm fetching array of objects from API using angular2 http get method. I would like an observable to return element of the array 1 by 1 with a short delay, how can I achieve this ? That's the code I have now:

```
return this.authHttp.get('fetch/arrayOfObjects',options).map(res => res.json());
```

I wan't it to work like the one below, so result is returned by a single element with a 1 second delay:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  let dt = [1,2,3,4,5];
  for(let e of dt){
     setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next(e);
  }, 1000);
  }
});

obs.subscribe(data=> console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `concatAll()` and then `delay()` to create the pause between each emission (I'm assuming that the remote service returns an array of objects):

```
return this.authHttp.get('fetch/arrayOfObjects',options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .concatAll() // unpack the array into single emissions
  .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val).delay(100)) // delay each emission
  .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `delay` operator. Please see [RxJs Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay).